# How to make a 1D VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to use `VectorPlot` to produce a 1 dimensional vector plot. I Have tried using `VectorPoints->{10,1}` but it produces an error as it wants at least 2 in each direction. Is there a way to make such a plot? For example:

```
d = 3;
n = 3;
k = 1;
c = Sqrt[(d-2)/(k(n-2))];
Show[
  VectorPlot[{-(d-2)+(n-2) k x^2, 0}, {x,0,3}, {y,-0.1,0.1}, VectorPoints -> {20, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> Large, StreamPoints -> 20], 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{{c,-1}, {c, 1}}]}]
]
```

But I only want a single line of vectors, and I'd like to clear up the `StreamPoints` to look nicer somehow. Perhaps it would be nice if the vectors were on one line and the stream lines below or something like that. I'm open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: What is a 1D vector plot?  Can you point to one on the web?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I added an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the actual points instead of how many:

```
Block[{d = 3, n = 3, k = 1, c},
 c = Sqrt[(d - 2)/(k (n - 2))];

 Show[
  VectorPlot[{-(d - 2) + (n - 2) k x^2, 0}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -0.1, 
    0.1},
   VectorPoints -> Table[{x, 0}, {x, 0, 3, 3./12}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> Large], 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{{c, -1}, {c, 1}}]}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

```
    Graphics[Table[
      Arrow[{{i, 0}, {i, 0} + {RandomReal[], 0}}], 
    {i, 1, 10, .5}]]
```

or for greater visibility:

```
Graphics[Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   Arrow[{{i, 0}, {i, 0} + {3 RandomReal[], 0}}]}, 
{i, 1, 20, 2}]]
```